# $_POST not being set with AJAX Post value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to send a JSON object to a .php file. What troubles me is that my POST value doesn't seem to get into PHP's $_POST array. Here is my code:

jQuery:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var obj = { //create json object to be sent
        "name": $("#name").val(),
        "email": $("#email").val(),
        "r1": $("#r1").val(),
        "r2": $("#r2").val(),
        "r3": $("#r3").val(),
        "intr1": $("#q1").val(),
        "intr2": $("#q2").val(),
        "intr3": $("#q3").val(),
        "set": "set1"
    };

    var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(obj);

    $.post(
        "updateAnswers.php",
        jsonObj,
        function() {
            //location.href = 'set2.php';
        }
    );
})
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST["jsonObj"])) { // value is empty
    $obj = json_decode($_POST['jsonObj'], true);

    $name = $obj['name'];
    $email = $obj['email'];

    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "concurs");
    $sql="INSERT into players values ('$name', '$email', '0', '0', '0')";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I dont think you need to stringify `obj` - try passing it straight to the `$.post` function.

Comment: Try to `var_dump()` or `print_r()` first $_POST array and check what you get from your script.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting.

Comment: There is no key named `jsonObj`  because that is just the name of the JS variable and has nothing to do with PHP. Learn about the difference between client- and serverside

Comment: See my full answer below. once you remove the stringify stuff, you still have a problem on your PHP side.

Comment: You are not sending any post data named `jsonObj` so `$_POST["jsonObj"]` will be empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I dont think you need to stringify `obj` - try passing `obj` straight to the `$.post` function.

```js
$.post("updateAnswers.php", obj, function() {
        //location.href = 'set2.php';
});
```

2. On the PHP side, the values `name`, `email`, `r1`, etc.. will be directly in the `$_POST` array.. so you will need to access `$_POST['name']` and so on.

```php
echo "Name: ". $_POST['name']; //Show name value
var_dump($_POST); //Show all passed values
```

3. Your `$sql` string does not check for SQL injection. You must (at the very least) replace single quotes with two single quotes like:

```php
 $sql = "INSERT into players values ('".str_replace("'","''", $name). "', '".str_replace("'","''", $email). "', '0', '0', '0')";
```

Comment: Replacing single quotes by double quotes does nothing to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Really? A hacker couldn't leverage that code vulnerability to end the sql statement and inject a new one? This is the first, most basic step is preventing it. This alone will not totally prevent it. That's why I wrote "(at the very least)".

Comment: You must (at the very least) bind parameters correctly.

Comment: Yeah I get it. This isn't a question about SQL injection, so I did not see the need to list out a full tutorial here. I simply mentioned it to let the OP know there was an issue with simply putting variable names inside double quotes for an SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are using stringify on your obj and then you pass it to the ajax-function.
But the ajax-function expects the object as objetct not as string.
So just remove `var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(obj);` and just use `obj`

Furtermore you have to check for

- name
- email
- r1
- ...

in your php-script instead of `jsonObj` because thats what the php actually gets from your script

Answer (score 0):

This with AJAX() send:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'updateAnswers.php',
   data: {'jsonObj': jsonObj},
   success: function(msg) {
     alert(msg);
   }
});
```